# I have a class, where I use "using Tanneryd.BulkOperations.EF6"; and I call Context.BulkInsertAll(List_To_Save);. No errors, but not saving

Tags: entity-framework, linq, bulkinsert

I have a class, where I take a list, pass it through several lambdas pass through several lists, and the compile at the end to a "List_To_Save".

```
        public void Save_All(List<My_EF_SQL_Table> List_To_Save)
        {
            using (var Context = new MySQLDBNAME())
            {
                //Context.My_EF_SQL_Table.AddRange(List_To_Save);
                //Context.SaveChanges();
                Context.BulkInsertAll(List_To_Save);
                Console.WriteLine("Saving Complete");
            }

        }
```

The issue is, if I do the add range option, it saves, but the bulkinsertall does not. The part that is puzzling is I do this all the time in other classes, the exact same way. this should work, but it moves past it, no bugs, but does not save. This data is almost 4 million records so the Add range .save changes is not really an option.

What could be causing this issue?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling using Tanneryd.BulkOperations.EF6 in Nuget. I have passed other items through other methods, and the base code works, but in this instance, it just wont.

It should be said, that basically I pull in the whole table at the beginning, run it through a few lambdas, but at the end, I do an AddRange to add them all back into a "List_To_Save" all have the exact same columns and modeled off my base SQL table.

I am adding an value in a column for every record, and I null it ahead of time, so when I run it after I run the code, for that column, I am still getting nothing but nulls, and the original Count stays the same. This test works and records get added when I do the AddRange method.

Comment: Looks like a bug for library that you use. Try [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#extensions)

Comment: You are correct, when I used a different bulk insert, I finally got a bug error dealing with my primary keys. Not sure why this one would not throw that exception, but thank you. I am going to go a different route, I think I am going to go the UpdateAll route, I was doing this as a truncate and re insert, but I think the more I think on it, the more it makes sense to update them instead over overwriting them.